# azure downgrade

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Is it possible to downgrade an Azure Cloud Service instance from "small" to "extra small" VM?

What I tried so far:
- Changed the VM in Visual Studio to "extra small"
- Built a new package
- Uploaded it to the Portal
- Updated the deployment. I checked "Allow update if role sizes or number of roles change."

The update fails with the following message:
"Failed to update the production environment.
The role size specified for role ... in the newly uploaded package differs from the role size for this role in the currently deployed service. The memory size specified in the currently deployed package is 1792. The memory size specified in the upgrade package is 768. "

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible for you to take down your cloud service for few minutes?

Comment: Yes, early in the morning, I can take it down.

Answer (score 3):

Checking the **Allow update if role sizes or number of roles changes** checkbox should work fine ([as documented here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-manage-a-cloud-service/)). The alternative would be to use a VIP swap:

1. Delete the deployment in staging
2. Upload your new package to staging
3. Perform the VIP swap (the new package with Extra Small instances in staging is now in production).

Note that in order to use a VIP swap, the endpoints of both packages should be exactly the same.

Comment: Checking the "Allow update if role size ... changes" checkbox did not work. I'll try the VIP swap.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the VIP swap method worked (I updated the "Staging" Environment with the new version, then pushed the Button "Swap"). Everything is fine now. 

Thanks for your answers!!

Answer (score 0):

While upgrading the cloud service and checking "Allow update if role sizes or number of roles change." should be work but there might be some issues(who knows).Also, some times the environment swip might also give error(Happend to me once!).
You can do one thing, simply just replace the web/worker role instead of upgrading it.
Or you can delete your role and reupload the one with Extrasmall size.

Answer (score 0):

While Upgrading  from SmallVm to Medium Vm  there is no problem, build a package with medium Vm and Update the deployment,

but when downgrading you need to delete the deployment and then upload a  fresh with required  vm size.

You can have different Vm size for Production and staging as per your choice.